# .htaccess underscores to hyphens, but first parameter should not be replaced, it is dynamic parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to replace underscores to dashes. I have tried this code and tried to change some parameters here, but i'm not yet friedly with .htaccess syntax so i failed to do it myself:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !\.(html|php)$ - [S=6]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3-$4 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2-$3 [E=underscores:Yes]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=underscores:Yes]

RewriteCond %{ENV:underscores} ^Yes$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

My previous .htacces code was this, it was working fine, but there was no need to replace underscores to dashes till now:

```
# Added for SME compatibility
Options +FollowSymLinks
# Ignore Indexation of apache
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules for ReRouting to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I have URL like this: `http://mydomain.tld/nl_BE/get_quote` , the language (1st parameter) should NOT be replaced with dash, also language parameter can change, so i cannot hardcode language name in .htaccess file.
So i want to have URL something like this:

```
http://mydomain.tld/nl_BE/get-quote/some-random-title

http://mydomain.tld/nl_NL/about-us/some-random-text
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than those multiple rules you can use this **generic recursive** rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

## RECURSION based rule
# if there is one underscore left then redirect
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}_[a-z]+)/([^_]*)_([^_]*)/?$ /$1/$2-$3 [NC,L,R=302]

# if there are more than one underscores then "repeatedly" replace it by -
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}_[a-z]+)/([^_]*)_(.*)$ $1/$2-$3 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks! I made it with PHP, but will try you code too. Thanks again!